# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined Javascript

Tags: javascript

The first time the loop runs, there's no problem. The get's shown when the loop ends, and every other time the loop runs.
The .checked property works fine, to my knowledge, there's just the error...
Does someone know what to do about this?
My background in javascript isn't that broad, and I'm still learning.
Thanks you.

I have already tried `.checked === true` and
             `.checked == checked`
              ...

In the code snippet below dishes is an array of radiobuttons.

```
    for (i = 0; i <= dishes.length; i++) {
       if (dishes[i].checked) {
         switch (dishesClass) {
        .........
         }
       }
     }
```

I expect no error in the console, but there are multiple. Every time the loop ends, the console states the same error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined

Comment: Can you show the code for adding values to dishes array

Comment: I swear that `Cannot read property x of undefined` is the most asked question on SO  Show us the current state of `dishes` please.

Comment: Ah, just remove the `<` from `<=`

Comment: `i <= dishes.length` -> `i < dishes.length` Last element in the array is `dishes[dishes.length - 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you are testing if `i` is less than **or equal to** `dishes.lengh`. You just need to check if it is less than, since `i` starts from `0`, as does array indexes in computing.

So just replace `i <= dishes.length;` with `i < dishes.length;`

Hope that helps

**This code will work**

```
for (i = 0; i < dishes.length; i++) {
   if (dishes[i].checked) {
     switch (dishesClass) {
    .........
     }
   }
 }
```

This resource, on [Loops and Iteration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by @Alicia, the problem is in your loop condition `i<=` whereas it should be `i<`. The array index **i** tries to access an element outside of the array bounds on the last iteration. Array's index starts at zero and ends at the array length - 1